# MySQL DB: Nullable bool in database column, enum, or two boolean columns, which one is more efficient?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing EF 6 code first with MVC 5. One of my classes has a property that can mean three things:

- Confirmed by user
- Has not answered yet
- Declined by user

My question is, what should I use?

1. A nullable bool, obviously mapped to the choices above
2. An enum (the column would store an integer as a foreign key to another table listing the states)
3. Or two bool columns (HasAnswered, IsConfirmed) where IsConfirmed only gets accessed if the user has answered

I am very thankful for every opinion you might have.

Comment: I suggest that you go with option 2, whether you use Enumerators for readability it's your own choice, but it does make the code more readable especially when you don't expect to add new statuses constantly.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer.. I thought you were suggesting an enum as a column datatype**

None of the above.

- *An enum*.. what if want to add more data to each status or rename one?
- *Nullable bool* .. as above, plus what if you need to add another status?
- *Two bool columns*.. same as above, plus you could introduce normalisation issues.

I'd go with a `tiny_int` called status (or something similar).

Mainly for flexibility.. if you need the status titles in the DB or need to add any other data to each option you can place it in another table and foreign key it in. If you don't you just need to translate the numbers somewhere.

Another option is to separate out the actions (the answer) from the state.

Consider an answer table with a column indicating confirmation or denial and a reference to the original table. By joining the tables it is possible to separate out the original rows that have no answers and those that have been confirmed/denied.

**UPDATE**

In response to Null's comment, an `int` is so much more powerful..

A status database table:

```
id, title, description, priority, cost... (attach extra data to the status)
```

Or in PHP pseudo code (without a table):

```
$query = new Query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = :status');
$query->bind('status'=>TableClass::STATUS_ANSWERED)
```

I wasn't suggesting you translate the numbers everywhere.. just somewhere.

The final great thing about an `int` is it separates meaning from the workings.. what if I want to rename one of the `enum`s? I change one row with a foreign key, or potentially millions with an `enum`.

Comment: The enum he described is exactly what you have described, but he simply wants it to be organized in his code as well so he doesn't write unreadable code similar to order.StatusId = 3 or write redundant comments to explain what on earth 3 stands for in a given context.

Comment: @Null see update. Readability is achievable fairly easily. I've tried using enum's before in projects and always ended up changing them

Comment: "An enum.. what if want to add more data to each status or rename one" - this is what you said, this is what I answer for. Making a complete new statement will require me to write a complete new answer. I am not sure if you know but you can have an integer behind a given enumerator, renaming the enumerator doesn't change the number. To illustrate what I mean, please review this image: http://i.imgur.com/2BcH2dV.png It doesn't disproves your latest proposal in any way, but shows that he can indeed use them as you suggested earlier, even though you said he can't.

Comment: Haha oops, I completely misread the question.. I thought OP was suggesting using an enum in the database (which is what the title suggests). An enum in the code is not something I considered.. I think if you've got a separate table, a separate class is probably easier with a lot of frameworks.. otherwise that looks sensible. Good points!